# NSMutableArray - Remove duplicates

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsmutablearray

i tried doing this: `Values = [[NSSet setWithArray:Values] allObjects];` and no sucess,

Thanks

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Your method should work, except it returns an `NSArray` instead of `NSMutableArray`. You could use

```
[values setArray:[[NSSet setWithArray:values] allObjects]];
```

to set `values` to the content of the new array.

Answer (score 23):

Note that the `NSSet` method may remove any order you have in your `NSArray`. You might want to loop thru your array to keep the order. Something like this:

```
NSMutableArray* uniqueValues = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; 
for(id e in Values)
{
    if(![uniqueValues containsObject:e])
    {
        [uniqueValues addObject:e];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 21):

```
NSMutableArray* myArray =
[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:
@"red",@"blue",@"red",@"green",@"yellow", @"33", @"33",@"red", @"123", @"123",nil];

NSOrderedSet *mySet = [[NSOrderedSet alloc] initWithArray:myArray];
myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[mySet array]];

NSLog(@"%@",myArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use Key Value Coding:

```
uniquearray = [yourarray valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.fieldNameTobeFiltered"];
```

Please refer the below article for complete understanding

[KVC Collection Parameters](http://nshipster.com/kvc-collection-operators/)