# NSDictionary objects with same keys

Tags: ios, xcode

I am parsing a `JSON` file and adding each object from the file in an `NSDictionary`. Sometimes it may happen that the elements in the file are equal. This means that more than 1 object in my `NSDictionary` will have the same bey and object. IF they have the same object, there is no problem, but if they have the same key something very strange happens. they get repeated many times, and its just chaos.

This is how I add objects to my dictionary:

```
NSArray *messagearray = [data objectForKey:@"message"];
NSArray *namearray    = [data objectForKey:@"name"];

CHOrderedDictionary* Dictionary = [CHOrderedDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:namearray forKeys:messagearray];
```

If instead all the keys are different, everything works just fine. Now, since this might happen... e.g.

> {"key":["vfg                                                                                    SJ45FFGJJ76v = 1357429260","v                                                                                    SJ45FFGJJ76v = 1640600269","gh                                                                                    SJ45FFGJJ76v = 330786894","gh                                                                                    SJ45FFGJJ76v = -2045929990","v                                                                                    SJ45FFGJJ76v = -1145652524","d                                                                                      SJ45FFGJJ76v = 1255089702","",""],"object":["G","T","G","G","G","R","",""]}
>
> ... 702","",""...

Is there a way to prevent this error? e.g. remove the duplicate key objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An NSDictionary (or subclass) **must** have unique keys, you can't have duplicates in it.

Saying that, you should take a look to this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3882515/remove-duplicates-nsmutablearray) to remove duplicate before creating your dictionary with the arrays.